# Don't want to use eval when instantiating object from String - help?

Tags: javascript, constructor, eval

I have the following legacy code that I'd like to remove eval from:

```
eval('view = new ' + o.base + '(o)');
```

The best I've come up with so far is ...

```
view = eval(o.base).prototype.constructor.apply(o)
```

... which obviously still uses eval. Can someone please help?

NOTE: The *o.base* variable is a qualified classname (e.g. "application.area.type.ClassName") referring to a valid function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
view = application.area.type[o.base].prototype.constructor.apply(o);
```

But you can still use `new`:

```
view = new application.area.type[o.base](o);
```

**UPDATE**

A more generic way to achieve this for `o.base` representing any qualified name would be:

```
var base = window;
for(var i=0,ns=o.base.split('.'); i<ns.length; ++i) {
   base = base[ns[i]];
}
view = new base(o);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the contents of the string, only that it will be in that format.

Comment: The *o.base* string. I know it will be a qualified class/function name, but I'm receiving *o* as an object param in the arguments of the function containing my original code, so I can't manually write out the *application.area.type...* bit above.

Comment: @Martin, I think I get what you're saying, I've updated my answer, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was hoping there might be a way of doing it without splitting out the string, but I guess not. That does make it a good deal longer than the single-line implementation. Guess it begs the question "in this instance, how evil is eval?". Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Martin, well the complexity doesn't really change because even the eval has to lookup each object in the exact same way the above code does. So eval certainly doesn't make things quicker here.